# Reading large packets over Tcp Client

Tags: c#, tcp

When using `TCP` client the `NetworkStream.read` method often doesn't return a totally filled buffer. How can I make it so it blocks further execution until it has written the whole array?

```
byte[] datagramByteForm = new byte[dgramSizeInt];
int j = dataIOStream.Read(datagramByteForm, 0, datagramByteForm.Length);//read the actual datagram
if (j != datagramByteForm.Length)
{
    throw new Exception("Connection j value: " + j + " expected amount: " + datagramByteForm.Length);
}
```

Comment: Maybe `BytesAvailable` is less that dgramSizeInt.

Comment: I usually use `TcpClient`, it possible to set           `tcpClient.Client.ReceiveBufferSize = 20000;`

Comment: the buffersize isn't the issue here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its actually pretty straight forward, you just need to use the provided arguments in the stream.read function.
Here is a example(untested):

```
        TcpClient TCC = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 200);
        int cOffset = 0, dgramSizeInt = 5000, j;
        byte[] datagramByteForm = new byte[dgramSizeInt];

        var dataIOStream = TCC.GetStream();

        while (cOffset <= dgramSizeInt)
        {
            j = dataIOStream.Read(datagramByteForm, cOffset, dgramSizeInt-cOffset);
            cOffset += j;
        }
```

Comment: I figured it out, you almost got it right. if you adjust dgramSizeInt in the stream.read I'll accept your anwer  ( int needToRead = datagramByteForm.Length;
                int readAmount = 0;
                int currentRead = 0;
                while ((needToRead = needToRead - currentRead) != 0) {
                   // needToRead = needToRead - readAmount;
                    currentRead = dataIOStream.Read(datagramByteForm, readAmount, needToRead);//read the actual datagram
                    readAmount += currentRead;
                })

Comment: (Your solution doesn't readjust the readlength in stream.read)

Comment: Yep, sorry my fault, but as i said i just wrote it down without compiling it :P (Edited)